# Changed my app's name, now every file is red on xcode

Tags: ios

every single of of my files are red and I cannot access them... I just changed my bundle, name and other info to a different name (app used to be called apple, now it's called orange with the bundle changed as well). Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you changed the name of a directory that contains your files--and now Xcode can't find any of the paths.  Change that directory back to the old name.  It doesn't matter as long as what's in your project settings and Info.plist contain the new name.

Comment: now I see just "My Mac" on the platform instead of my device. How to fix this problem?

Comment: close and re-open your project file.

Answer (score 0):

A: To change the name appearing underneath your app icon, modify the CFBundleDisplayName key in your Info.plist. Follow these steps to modify CFBundleDisplayName:

In Xcode, select your target under "Targets" in the project navigator.
Select the Info pane.
Click the disclosure button next to Custom iOS Target Properties to reveal a property list editor of keys and values.
By default, Xcode displays a human-readable string of a key rather than its actual name. So, search the property list for "Bundle display name". click over there and write the name that you want to display.

source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1823/_index.html

to access everything.,go back and change the names to previous one as @nicholas said